# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, opencv

So after having a lot of trouble with importing cv2 , I now have this error showing up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/Projet/IDO/ido-security-cam/code.py", line 19, in <module>
    dataFrame = cv2.DataFrame(columns = ["start","end"])
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

Yes, I do have the same python version on my interpreter and in vscode (3.7.3).
I already installed opencv both versions because I was desperate. Here are the commands I tried :

```sh
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
pip3 install opencv-python
```

The error shows up knowing that I use other cv2 methods like `cv2.VideoCapture()` and it doesn't send me back error. I just don't why the `DataFrame()` method won't work. DataFrame is from the Pandas library which is already installed but not imported.
I really don't know what to try next...

Thanks in advance for you help !

Comment: Do you mean DataFrame from Pandas?

Comment: yes, DataFrame is a pandas concept/class, not a OpenCV one.

Comment: @yuRa Yes sorry, I edit that, I commented in my code the import Pandas because It wasn't recognized "No Module named 'Pandas'"
So if DataFrame is a pandas method, how can I fix the Pandas import ? (already tried pip3 install pandas and it is already installed)

Comment: What version of python and pip are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.7.3.

Comment: So is opencv or pandas the issue here? I am a bit confused. Also cv2 does not have a Dataframe() you need to use pd.Dataframe().

Comment: The code I used was perfectly working on another coputer, and when I tried it on this one It doesn't work (maybe I made an oopsie). What you say makes sense, so I'm going to try using a panda attribute.

Comment: pandas and Pandas are not the same thing, python is case sensitive, you need to import pandas

Comment: And we do not really believe that cv2.DataFrame actually works, it does not work here, your code was probably different and using pandas.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, indeed using and panda.DataFrame() it is now working, must have been a manipumation error, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I did trust a code that was previously working that's why I didn't see this error.

*Dataframe* is a function part of the pandas module, so of course it won't work using *cv2*. To make it works, you need to use *pandas.DataFrame()*

Thanks again !